# List all foreground running apps' names

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, win32gui, psutil

I want to retrieve all apps' or process' names (for example: Google Chrome,...) with Python like what is being shown here (taken from Task Manager):

[image: image of working apps' name]

My question is, how to get all foreground apps' names (or executables' names) in Python?
Based on a comment on [an another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55289725/22134043), there is no way to do that beforehand, so how did Task Manager manage to get the names as shown in the image above?

---

I have tried using `psutil` but it gave me all processes' names, including the ones which are running in background (which I don't need).

```py
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    print(process.name())
```

I also tried `win32gui` but it only gave me the windows' titles, not apps' or processes' names like I needed.

```py
import win32gui

def callback(hwnd, _):
    item=win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if item and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        print(item)

win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```py
>>> ["Google Chrome", "PyCharm", "Task Manager", "Windows Explorer"]
```

or

```py
>>> ["chrome.exe", "pycharm64.exe", "Taskmgr.exe", "explorer.exe"]
```

Comment: this is a good question. i am also interested in the same.